# I get the following error "(0 , _reactNavigation.TabNavigator) is not a function" any time I try to add tab navigation to my react-native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a simple react-native project in [expo](https://snack.expo.io/@ojakovo/assignment-1-revamp). Where I have a login page in one scene and another tab-navigator in another scene. What I want to achieve is the Loginpage switching to the HomePage(the tab-navigator) via the route when a login is successful. My App.js which is my main file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Scene, Router, Actions, Stack } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import TestPage from './components/TestPage';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {

    return (
      <Router>
        <Stack>
          <Scene key="First" component={HomePage}  initial = {true} hideNavBar={true} />
          <Scene key="Second" component={LoginPage} hideNavBar={true} />
          <Stack>
            <Scene key="Third" component={LoginPage} />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Since I haven't programmatically written the code that switches scene when login is successful, I test my scenes by making them the first Scenes in the route. When I want to test my LoginPage I do this:

```
<Scene key="First" component={LoginPage}  initial = {true} hideNavBar={true} />
```

The above shows up well, but when I want to test my HomePage which is the tab Navigator:

```
<Scene key="First" component={HomePage}  initial = {true} hideNavBar={true} />
```

I get the following error:

```
> (0 , _reactNavigation.TabNavigator) is not a function
  Evaluating module://components/HomePage.js.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js
TypeError: (0 , _reactNavigation.TabNavigator) is not a function
    at Object.eval (module://components/HomePage.js.js!transpiled:58:60)
    at eval (module://components/HomePage.js.js!transpiled:78:4)
    at eval (module://components/HomePage.js.js!transpiled:79:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at [snack internals]
    at Object.n ([snack internals]
    at e.evaluate ([snack internals]
    at He ([snack internals]
    at [snack internals]
    at https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/snack-web-player-staging/35/static/js/app.7b999a95.chunk.js:1:14289
```

I am really confused I feel this is a dependency issue, but I am unsure how to resolve it. The snippet of my HomePage.js is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FirstPage from './fragments/FirstPage';
import SecondPage from './fragments/SecondPage';
import ThirdPage from './fragments/ThirdPage';
import FourthPage from './fragments/FourthPage';
import {
    StackNavigator,
    TabNavigator,
    DrawerNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomePage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <SimpleAppNavigator/>
        )
    }
}
const SimpleAppNavigator = TabNavigator({
    page1: {screen: FirstPage},
    page2: {screen: SecondPage},
    page3: {screen: ThirdPage},
    page4: {screen: FourthPage}
},{
     initialRouteName: 'page1',
     swipeEnabled: true,
     animationEnabled: true,
     lazy: false,
     tabBarPosition:'bottom',
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First install `react-navigation-tabs` if you don't have it already, then use `createBottomTabNavigator` instead of `TabNavigator`:

```js
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

// ...

const SimpleAppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    // ...
})
```

Check the [Tab navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) for further details.

Comment: Still the same having the same issue